# What are marginal fields in CFT?

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, scale-invariance

In this [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0304234v2) they call weight $(h,\bar{h})=(1,1)$ fields marginal.

Why are these fields called [marginal](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=marginal+deformation+cft)? Why are they to be distinguished.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This terminology comes from [renormalization group flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group), where one has [*relevant,* *marginal,* and *irrelevant* operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group#Relevant_and_irrelevant_operators.2C_universality_classes).

In [CFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_field_theory), operators with conformal weight $(1, 1)$ are known as *marginal* operators. More generally, operators of conformal weight $(h, \bar{h})$ are said to be *relevant* if $h + \bar{h} < 2$  and *irrelevant* if $h + \bar{h} > 2$. A (necessarily marginal) operator that preserves conformality is called *truly marginal,* or *exactly marginal,* etc, cf. Ref. 1.

References:

1. P. Ginsparg, *Applied Conformal Field Theory,*  [arXiv:hep-th/9108028](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028); Section 8.6.

Comment: Fun fact: There are [dangerously irrelevant operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerously_irrelevant_operator).

Answer (score 8):

They are called *marginal* because they correspond to "slight deformations" of a CFT, which do not break conformal invariance. Given a marginal field $\phi$, one can add to the action a term

$$ \delta S = \Delta \int_\Sigma \phi$$

which is just the operator integrated over the worldsheet, modulated by a deformation parameter $\Delta$. Since the (2D) integration measure transforms exactly oppositely to the marginal field, this term is conformally invariant, and hence produces a new theory that is still conformally invariant.

Therefore, it is possible to study new CFTs by producing them by disturbing those already known - the idea is to "probe" the CFT landscape starting from "nice" theories, e.g. rational CFTs.