# String length $\gg$ Planck length?

Tags: string-theory, dimensional-analysis, quantum-gravity, physical-constants

The potential energy of a string $E_{pot}$ is given by
$$E_{pot}=T \times L\tag{1}$$
where $T$ is the string tension and $L$ is the length of the string.

The internal kinetic energy $E_{kin}$ of a string at rest, with no translational velocity, is due to quantum zero-point fluctuations

$$E_{kin} \times \frac{L}{c} \approx \hbar,$$

$$E_{kin} \times L \approx 1.\tag{2}$$

where we use natural units with $\hbar=c=1$. (**I have no evidence for this statement - I just guessed it - see comment below by ACuriousMind**).

As the string is a bound object (using the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) with $n=1$) we must have

$$E_{kin} \approx E_{pot}.\tag{3}$$
Therefore substituting Eqn.$(1)$ and Eqn.$(2)$ into Eqn.$(3)$ we obtain
$$T\approx\frac{1}{L^2}.\tag{4}$$

If we assume that the rest mass energy $M$ of the string is given by its total energy then we have

$$M = E_{kin} + E_{pot} \approx 1/L\tag{5}$$

so that by substituting Eqn.$(5)$ into Eqn.$(4)$ we obtain

$$T \approx M^2.\tag{6}$$

It seems perfectly reasonable physically that a string of rest mass $M \approx T \times L$ should have a tension $T \approx M^2$ and a length $L \approx 1/M$.

However, as I understand it, string theory implies that strings have a length of the order of the Planck length $l_{Pl}=1/M_{Pl}$ and a tension $M^2_{Pl}$.

Does my crude semi-classical picture of a particle, represented as a string fluctuating with zero-point energy held together with string tension, give no physical understanding at all?

Comment: That's...just not how string theory works. See e.g. my answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/307315/50583) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/458354/50583) for why string theory is *not* just the theory of classical strings floating through space. In particular my first answer shows that particles are not "represented by strings", but by *quantum excitation modes of strings*. Also: Can you provide citations for bold assertions like *"The internal kinetic energy of a string at rest, with no translational velocity, is due to quantum zero-point fluctuations"*?

Comment: Ok thanks I stand corrected. I'll have a look at your very informative answers. I shouldn't have made the statement above as I don't have any citation to support it.